# How to use arbitrary length sequences of values as map keys in Go?

Tags: dictionary, go

Edit: Jeremy Wall helped me realize I had asked a question more specific than I intended; here's a better version.

Say I want to represent a table associating of values of some type B to sequences of values of some type A for which equality is defined. What is the best way to do that in Go?

Obviously for the table I'd want to use a Go map, but what can I use for the sequences of values of type A? Slices cannot be used as keys for maps in Go; arrays can, but the length of an array is a part of it's type and I'm interested in being able to use sequences of length determined at runtime. I could (1) use arrays of A declaring a maximum length for them or (2) use slices of A, serialize them to strings for use as keys (this technique is familiar to Awk and Lua programmers...). Is there a better work around for this "feature" of Go than the ones I've described?

As pointed out by Jeremy Wall in answer to my original version of the question, where I had A = int, option (2) is pretty good for integers, since you can use slices of runes for which conversion to string is just a cast.

Comment: I gave "an" answer below but the question is really too specific to really lead to any kind of an answer. It would help to know what problem specifically you are trying to answer.

Comment: That's a good point about the question being too specific. My idea was to mention integers just to give a concrete example, but I hadn't thought that there might be a really good and simple solution for integers that wouldn't work for other types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will a sequence of rune instead of integers work for you? runes are uint32 and the conversion to a string is just a cast:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myKey struct {
  seq []int
}

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    key := []rune{1, 2}
    m[string(key)] = "foo"
    fmt.Print("lookup: ", m[string(key)])
}
```

You can play with this code here: http://play.golang.org/p/Kct1dum8A0

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat trick! To make sure I understand: here the variable "key" is of type _slice_ of rune, right? This perfectly covers the case of sequences of integers, but although that lets me improve the program I had written (that enumerates all [de Bruijn sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) of a given length), I had meant to ask the question more generally for sequences of values which are not necessarily just 32 bit integers.

Comment: yes key is a slice of runes. Keep in mind that runes are unsigned 32 bit integers. If your sequences of integers will fit in that then they can stand in for a slice of int.

Comment: If your sequences are all the same length, you can use an array of the most appropriate numeric type.  Thats array not slice.  Arrays are valid map keys (within restrictions...  Arrays of numeric types are no problem though.)  Might even be slightly faster than slices.